# How to use a trigger that gets the next value in a sequence

Tags: oracle10g, triggers, sequences, toad

I'm just learning Oracle and I understand the concept of triggers and sequences. What I can't seem to find is how they are used together in an auto-increment fashion similar to a SqlServer Identity setting. In a really simple example, I have a table called Employees that has three fields (all required): EmployeeID (PK), FirstName, LastName. I have created a sequence to get the next value for the ID field. I then created a trigger that looks like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MyFirstTrigger
 BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEES  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   Select EMP_SEQ.NextVal into :NEW.EMPLOYEEID from dual;
END MyFirstTrigger;
/
```

However, how is this used in an insert statement? An insert statement with only the FirstName and LastName values fails for "Not enough values" (I'm using Toad, by the way). If I have to include EMP_SEQ.NextVal as the first value of the insert statement, what's the point of the trigger?

Hopefully, this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit the ID from the insert, but you must specify the target columns:

```
insert into employees (firstname, lastname) values ('Tony', 'Andrews');
```

You should not have inserts without a column list in production code; however if you did you could just pass a NULL for the D column:

```
insert into employees values (null, 'Tony', 'Andrews');
```

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I needed to know. It's so simple, but I couldn't find anything on the Internet or in the Oracle User's guide. Maybe it's assumed that people just know this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if not i will describe the possible reason of that and usage.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('Name', 'LastName')
```

and for sure You will be able to do this

```
   INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEEID , FirstName, LastName) VALUES (null, 'Name', 'LastName')
```